# How to fix Intelij "Cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: java, ide

I have been trying to make a calculator in javafx and i keep getting error tht's not making me run the program :(

code :

```
import javax.swing.;import java.awt.;import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JTextField textField;
    JButton[] NumberButtons = new JButton[10];
    JButton[] FunctionButtons = new JButton[8];
    JButton addButton , subButton , mulButton , divButton;
    JButton decButton , eqlButton , clrButton , delButton;
    JPanel panel;
    
    Font myfont = new Font("8514oem", Font.BOLD,30);
    double num1 = 0 , num2 = 0 , result= 0;
    char operator;
    
    void Calculator(){    
        frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420,550);
        frame.setLayout(null);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Calculator calc = new Calculator(); /* this is the part where it is showing the error "cannot resolve symbol "Calculator" */
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

i was trying to run this program to see if my Jframe was working or not. But due to this error i couldn't...

Comment: To instanciate an object Calculator, you need a class Calculator, there is none

Comment: @azro how to do tht ?

Comment: Are you sure your class should be called `Main` and not `Calculator`? Also if you would rename it you should probably change `void Calculator(){ ... }` to `Calculator(){ ... }` to be constructor rather than method (constructors don't have return type, not even `void`).

Comment: This is not an Intellij problem or an IDE problem.  You will get an analogous error message if you attempt to compile this using a Java builld tool or by running `javac` from the command prompt.  This is simply a *commonly encountered* Java compilation error, caused by an error in your source code.  Read the duplink for the many things that can cause this error message ... and how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

The error "cannot resolve symbol **Calculator**" is because the class name is "**Main**," not "**Calculator**." You should change the line **Calculator calc = new Calculator();** to **Main calc = new Main();**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JTextField textField;
    JButton[] NumberButtons = new JButton[10];
    JButton[] FunctionButtons = new JButton[8];
    JButton addButton, subButton, mulButton, divButton;
    JButton decButton, eqlButton, clrButton, delButton;
    JPanel panel;

    Font myfont = new Font("8514oem", Font.BOLD, 30);
    double num1 = 0, num2 = 0, result = 0;
    char operator;

    public Main() {
        frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420, 550);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(50, 25, 300, 50);
        textField.setFont(myfont);
        frame.add(textField);

        // Add buttons, panels, and set their properties here

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main calc = new Main();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Handle button clicks here
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh i see thank you :) It fixed it :)